# How to do performance testing of non server application

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing

I have to conduct performance testing of an application which is not a web server. This application picks the data from a database and pushes into Kafka. What could be the strategy? In particular, when I look at the JMeter for ex, it says about making a REST request and getting the response to measure the peeformance. But in my case, this application does not server any service. I was wondering how to proceed..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`This application picks the data from a database` - what is the trigger for the application to pick the data from the database? If it is something which can be invoked externally you need to identify what [network protocols](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lists_of_network_protocols) are being used and whether JMeter supports this protocols with its [Samplers](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#samplers) or via [JMeter Plugins](https://jmeter-plugins.org/) or if there are client libraries you can use from the [JSR223 Test Elements](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#jsr223)

If you can trigger this reading from the database and pushing into Kafka event - you're good to go, if not - you need to identify the scope, to wit what you're testing and what you're trying to achieve.

1. If you need to load test the application itself - it makes sense to use [profiling tools](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_performance_analysis_tools) to check what are the slowest functions, largest objects, the most resource consuming routines, etc.
2. If you need to load test the database, to wit simulate the application reading the data from the database at high rate - this can be done using JMeter's [JDBC Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JDBC_Request) sampler, check out [Building a Database Test Plan](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/build-db-test-plan.html) article for more details
3. If you need to load test your Kafka instance - it can be done using [Pepper-Box - Kafka Load Generator](https://github.com/GSLabDev/pepper-box), check out [Apache Kafka - How to Load Test with JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-kafka-how-to-load-test-with-jmeter/) article for comprehensive information.